# Define recursive query for records with variable root

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hi am trying to import data into my data warehouse and to simplify importing some data I want to make a new column in a table that will keep track of the most current value as I get new data.

My tables look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerFact(
 Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
,CustomerId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL --Current Id of a Customer
);

--Track changes to CustomerId
CREATE TABLE CustomerHistoryFact(
 Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
,CurrentCustomerId NVARCHAR(20) --Most recent Customer Id
,CustomerId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL --Customer Id at time of record insert
,PrvsCustomerId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL --Customer Id at time of transaction
,PrvsCustomerIdEffectiveDate DATE NOT NULL --Date when PrvsCustomerId was effective
,PrvsCustomerIdObsoleteDate DATE NOT NULL --When the PrvsCustomerId was expired and replaced with a new Customer Id
);
```

The `CustomerId`, `PrvsCustomerId`, `PrvsCustomerIdEffectiveDate`, and `PrvsCustomerIdObsoleteDate` are all external. I want to assign a `CurrentCustomerId` whenever a new record is inserted.

This is determined by when a new `CustomerHistoryFact` is inserted, check the `PrvsCustomerId` with the `CurrentCustomerId` of all other records. If there is a match then the `CustomerId` of the new record becomes the `CurrentCustomerId` of all previous records or else the record is inserted and the `CustomerId` becomes the `CurrentCustomerId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a twisted database design. Why can't you just keep on inserting `CustomerId` in `CustomerHistoryFact` table, everytime the `CustomerFact` record is updated? You can write a  trigger on `CustomerFact` table for insert/update, and make an entry into `CustomerHistoryFact` table, if the latest CustomerId sorted by `CustomerIdEffectiveDate desc` is different from the customerId in Inserted/Deleted table. That way, you have a history of CustomerId's for starting from current CustomerId to back to in time.

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerFact(
 Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
,CustomerId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL --Current Id of a Customer
);

--Track changes to CustomerId
CREATE TABLE CustomerHistoryFact(
 Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
,CustomerId NVARCHAR(20) --Most recent Customer Id
,PrevCustomerId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL --Customer Id at time of record insert
,UpdatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL --Date when PrvsCustomerId was effective
);

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CustomerFact_IU
ON dbo.CustomerFact
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --
    -- Check if this is an INSERT, UPDATE.
    -- 
    DECLARE @action as char(1);
    DECLARE @oldCustomerId NVARCHAR(20);

    SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    SELECT @oldCustomerId = customerId from DELETED
    BEGIN
        SET @action = 
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
            END
    END
    ELSE 
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN; -- Nothing updated or inserted.

    IF @action = 'I' OR @action = 'U'
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerHistoryFact
         SELECT CustomerId, @oldCustomerId, GETUTCDATE() FROM INSERTED 
    END 

    END
```

Comment: The thing to consider is that I'm importing the `CustomerFact` and `CustomerHistoryFact` from an existing data source. They will be providing incremental updates to their data over time, so I will need to import their changes into the existing data set. Your strategy may work and I will look into it.

Comment: The thing is that PrvsCustomerIdEffectiveDate and PrvsCustomerIdObsoleteDate  can be rolled into one column UpdatedDate. This is because updatedDate of one CustomerHistoryFact record, become obsolete date for the previous record.

Comment: The problem is how will I take in new data for the `CustomerHistoryFact` table which augments the existing data while still preserving this scheme?

Comment: If the customerId from external CustomerHistoryFact table already exists in your CustomerHistoryFact and their ObsoleteDate > UpdatedDate, then replace your UpdatedDate with their ObsoleteDate, else, if the customerId does not exist on your side, then insert a new record into your CustomerHistoryFact table, and set UpdatedDate to their EffectiveDate, and ignore the ObsoleteDate. If they have got customers all the time, then EfectiveDate of current record should match ObsoleteDate of previous record.